# JS: Check if word "handover" contains "hand"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on this simple, straightforward `text content filtering` mechanism on our `post commenting` module where people are prohibited from writing `foul, expletive` words.

So far I'm able to compare (word-by-word, using `.include()`) comment contents against the blacklisted words we have in the database. But to save space, time and effort in entering database entries for each word such as `'Fucking'` and `'Fuck'`, I want to create a mechanism where we check if a `word` contains a `blacklisted word`.

This way, we just enter `'Fuck'` in the database. And when visitor's comment contains `'Fucking'` or `'Motherfucker'`, the function will automatically detect that there is a word in the comment that contain's `'fuck'` in it and then perform necessary actions.

I've been thinking of integrating `.substring()` but I guess that's not what I need.

Btw, I'm using `React` (in case you know of any built-in functions). Much as possible, I wanna deviate from using libraries for this mechanism.

Thanks a heap!

Comment: Just a word of warning on trying to match words within words - if one of your blacklisted words is "ass" then it's going to match with words like "classic" etc. So, by all means use this approach, but please be aware of its limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect if a string has another string inside of it you can simply use the .includes method, it does not work on a word by word basis but checks for a sequence of characters so it should meet you requirements. It returns a boolean value for if the string is inside the other string

```js
var sentence = 'Stackoverflow';

console.log(sentence.includes("flow"));
```

Comment: Man how did we skip this lol Our DB guy was entering words like 'fucking' 'asshole' no wonder why 'fuck' and 'ass' didn't work with .includes() rofl We might need to take a break. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 3):

```
"handover".indexOf("hand")
```

It will return index if it exists otherwise -1

To ignore cases you can define all your blacklisted words in lower case and then use this

```
"HANDOVER".toLowerCase().indexOf("hand")
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with `.includes()`

```
console.log('handover'.includes('hand'));
```

Returns true